# C# If have 3 Form , Can I show Form3 and close Form1 and Form2?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 3 Form. I want to show **Form3** and close **Form1, Form2** when click button in **Form2**. This is my code . when I run this code it can show **Form3** but not close **Form1**.

**Form1**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
    frm2.ShowDialog();
    //frm2.Show();
}
```

**Form2**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form3 frm3 = new Form3();
    Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
    frm3.Show();

    frm1.Hide();  // It not close Form1
    this.Hide();
    // frm1.Close();
    // this.Close();
}
```

Comment: In your program.cs file I'd imagine its opening the real form 1, "It not close form1" because youve just created an instance of form1 that is never opened. If program.cs is opening form1 then no, you cannot close this as you are expecting

Answer (score 6):

**Problem :** You are creating the newinstance of Form1 and then trying to close/hide it.

**Solution:** You need to get the `Form1` instance which was already in Memory and then hide or close it.

Replace This:

```
Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
frm1.Hide();  // It not close Form1
```

With This:

```
Form1 form1 = (Form1) Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
Form3 frm3 = new Form3();
frm3.Show();   
form1.Hide();
```

Comment: Won't this still just close the whole program since form1 is the parent?

Comment: @Sayse: check my edited answer, now it opens the form3 and then hides the form1

Comment: Fair enough, OP should still note that this doesn't close the form though and it will still hold any data it has